# How to move incoming mail to specific folder based on the subject?

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I move incoming mail from inbox to specific folder based on the subject name?

1. If Subject contains **Urgent** word then move this mail to **QuickLook** subfolder. Not needed for existing mails in Inbox.
2. I want to use **run as script** in my rules wizard for a new rule so it applies to every message that I receive in Inbox.

I know I can achieve it by Outlook rules but need this as macro as per my requirement.

Comment: Please don't mark it as duplicate, similar questions are not giving me the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Save the below script as Module.

```
Public Sub MoveUrgentMails(myItem As Outlook.MailItem)

 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("QuickLook")
 
 If InStr(myItem.Subject, "Urgent") > 0 Then
    myItem.Move myDestFolder
 End If

End Sub
```